# How to get other product details using SKU in another product page in Bigcommerce

Tags: product, bigcommerce

I am trying to get product data using SKU in another product detail page of Bigcommerce website. I need to show some of the Product based on the Particular SKU in product detail page like Related Products.

Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stencil utils to request a product's information by its ID:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/stencil-utils-api-reference#Product

The function takes three arguments: the product ID, a presentation template, and a callback:

```
window.stencilUtils.api.product.getById(productID, { template: 'products/template' }, (err, response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```